# Error when request a nvarchar type in webform from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

I have a table in my SQL Server database:

```
DOCUMENT(DOC_NUM,DOC_NAME,...)
{
 DOC_NUM: nvarchar(50);
...
}
```

And table `DOC_NUM` has one row with `DOC_NUM= DD121`;

And in webform I execute a query:

```
string docnum= "DD121";
string sql= "select * from DOCUMENT where DOC_NUM="+docnum;
Datatable doc= ....EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
int count= doc.Rows.Count;
```

It causes an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

on the line of code:

```
int count= doc.Rows.Count;
```

But when I change it to:

```
string sql= "select * from DOCUMENT where DOC_NUM= 'DD121'";
    Datatable doc= ....EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
    int count= doc.Rows.Count;
```

It worked fine!

I don't really know why?

Comment: take a look at my edit above dear ^^, it really has one row with docnum= DD121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this exception because you missed single quotes when you specify  `DOC_NUM` value. It Should be `"select * from DOCUMENT where DOC_NUM='"+docnum +"'";`

These errors can be avoid by [using SQL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements) and it is more secure.

Comment: @VyClarks - From "it worked" I assume you ignored the advice about SQL Parameters and just used `where DOC_NUM='"+docnum +"'"`. In that case your web application is likely open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 5):

When you use this string concatenation, your query will be `DOC_NUM= DD121` instead of `DOC_NUM= 'DD121'` which is wrong.

And this kinf of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* instead;

```
string sql= "select * from DOCUMENT where DOC_NUM = @docnum";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docnum", docnum);
```